# Visual Studio plugin access type on a short cut menu

Tags: c#, visual-studio, plugins, visual-studio-2013

I try to write a plugin where I need to access the object where the user opened the short cut menu. (Explanation of short cut menu: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165623.aspx)

Example:

```
public class MyPublicClass
{
  private void myMethod()
  {
    public MyClass class = new MyClass();
  }
}
```

If the user right clicks on class than I need to know the type "MyClass". This should work for any type and any class.

Things I have done so far:

1. I know how to create a plugin.
2. Tried using CodeElementFromPoint. ( not working )
3. Tried using http://www.mztools.com/articles/2006/MZ2006009.aspx ( If iam using vsCMElementClass this just returns MyPublicClass but not MyClass.)

I need to know the type because I want to generate something via reflection.

( I am writing the addin with c#)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out, that this is not possibly. This is mentioned somewhere in the docs too. The deepest point you can reach with FileCodeModel is the method level. Things inside a method can not be accessed.

But there is a nice solution. You can use the Roslyn compiler. With this new open source compiler you can access every type, every property etc. of the code.